# Sort on click of Button, If again pressed then order to be changed to default sort order in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

ii)    Sort Button : this new button needs to be introduced to change the default sort order , once this button is clicked or pressed then records should be sorted based on ascending order of Policy Number 
    Note: If this button is pressed again then sort order should be changed to default sort order (same as it exists in current functionality)

```
****Sort Button Code below:
====================**

Declare
    chk varchar2(100);
Begin
    if :global.chk_stat  = 1 then
        chk:= 'status'; 
        SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('BLOCK1',ORDER_BY,chk);
        go_block('block1');
        Execute_query(all_records);
        :global.chk_stat := 2;
    Else
        SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('BLOCK1',ORDER_BY,:cntrl.default_sort);
        go_block('block1');
        Execute_query(all_records);
        :global.chk_stat := 1;
    End If;
End;


**Code in New form Instance Trigger
====================================**

:cntrl.default_sort := GET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('BLOCK1',ORDER_BY);
```

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 0):

Think the current status for ordering dependent on what `Get_Block_Property` method brings :

```
Begin
    If  Get_Block_Property('block1',Order_By) = ' Policy Desc' Then
    -- presuming the above one is your default "Order By Clause" 
        Set_Block_Property('block1',Order_By,' Policy ');
        :global.chk_stat := 2;
    Else
        Set_Block_Property('block1',Order_By,' Policy Desc');
        :global.chk_stat := 1;
    End If;
        Go_Block('block1');
        Execute_query;    
End;
```

Perhaps you use at some other part. So, `:global.chk_stat` assignments still remain.